# Amazon LEX control audio playback time

Tags: amazon-web-services, audio, controls, playback, amazon-lex

I have built an amazon LEX based chatbot, that will respond to users' queries on a certain topic *(not disclosed). Since some of the responses are big (maybe over 500 words, it is very ungainly to playback entire audio)*, I would like to control the length of the audio playback from LEX. In other words, when the response says over 100 words (or 1 or 2 mins etc), I would like to be able to stop the playback / not play the content at all - except to advice the user to read the response themselves.

```
Joanna - "Dear user, since the response to your question is long, kindly 
read through the response posted below" - something to that effect?
```

How can I code the above scenario?